# IntelliJ IDEA's best practices to perform git show

Tags: git, intellij-idea

I want to get the version of some specific file in other branch without switching to that very  branch. While coding in `vim` I can just type something like `:!git show some_other_branch:file_name`. What about IDEA, what is the best way to perform the same task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can right click somewhere in the file, choose `Git->Compare with Branch...` and then just select the branch you want.

Comment: oh, that's nice one, I've missed it. I've seen this in menu but thought that this is basically the same as Ctrl + V.